# Error in Array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have the next program, and I have a problem when I introduce data in the struct

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>


struct message{

char msg[];

};


int main(void)
{

    int i=0;

    struct message messag[2];

    messag[0].msg[]={ 'a', 't','\r', '\n'};


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++. Class data members must have complete types.

Comment: You should use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) for this part: `messag[0].msg[]={ 'a', 't','\r', '\n'};`. The syntax is only allowed for compile time initialization.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The error is `error: excepted primary expression before ']' token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure definition

```
struct message{

char msg[];

};
```

is wrong because the type of msg is incomplete. The size of the array is unknown.

Also arrays do not have the assignment operator. So you may not write like

```
messag[0].msg[]={ 'a', 't','\r', '\n'};
```

(this statement simply syntaxically incorrect) or

```
messag[0].msg={ 'a', 't','\r', '\n'};
```

You could use the last statement if msg would be declared like `std::array<char, 4>`. For example

```
#include <array>

//...

struct message
{
    std::array<char, 4> msg;
};
```

If the size of the array is not known at compile-time then you need to allocate the array dynamically. For example you could use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>   

struct message
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> msg;
};


int main()
{
    message message[2];

    message[0].msg.reset( new char[4] { 'a', 't','\r', '\n' } );

    return 0;
}
```

The other approach is to use standard class `std::string`. For example

```
#include <string>

struct message
{
    std::string msg;
};

int main()
{
    message message[2];

    message[0].msg = { 'a', 't','\r', '\n' };

    return 0;
}
```